# Algorithm to get the entries of a table?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multiple-entries

Say I have this table of non-negative entries:

```
    1   2   3   sum
1   4   5   1   10
2   6   12  7   25
3   0   3   14  17
4   7   2   5   14
sum 17  22  27  66
```

given:

1. the number of columns C and number of rows R
2. the two sums entries (the sum of each row and the sum of each column)
3. and the total (66 in this example)

The goal is to produce the entries of the table (the inner cells; not the same ones. but, the sum must be equal to the given ones for each row and each column) 
all entries must be positive values.

Any pseudo code to do it?

Comment: thanks but this answer is very short :D can you please elaborate more?

Comment: There are many solutions possible. Are there any additional constraints, like the numbers must be positive?

Comment: yes. the entries must be all positive and the sums must be equal to the given ones. these are the only contraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my pseudo code. This rule named something like "Rule of North-West corner" (I unable find real name of this rule on wiki)

```
row = 1
col = 1

while (col <= C && row <= R)
  Matrix[col, row] = Min(colsum[col], rowsum[row])
  colsum[col] = colsum[col] - Matrix[col, row]
  rowsum[row] = rowsum[row] - Matrix[col, row]
  while (col <= C && colsum[col] == 0) col++
  while (row <= R && rowsum[row] == 0) row++

Print Matrix;
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through the table cells in any order you like. At each step put the largest number there that is still allowed by the two sum constraints.

For example if we go row by row:

```
10  0  0
 7 18  0
 0  4 13
 0  0 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of linear equations like;
X+ Y + .. = sum

For each row and each column.
And solve the using the standard methods of solving linear equations.

Comment: thanks! sounds good but i think i need something like code. do you think it can be applied? or do you have another pseudo-code idea?